# How can I merge these 2 PHP scripts?

Tags: php, validation, jquery, syntax

I have a jQuery AJAX form and I'd like for it to do better validation on input - on the PHP side. Here is the PHP script that works with AJAX:

```
while (true) {
if (empty($_POST['name'])) {
    $return['error'] = true;
    $return['msg'] = 'You did not enter your name.';
    break;
}

if (empty($_POST['email'])) {
    $return['error'] = true;
    $return['msg'] = 'You did not enter your email.';
    break;
}

if (empty($_POST['message'])) {
    $return['error'] = true;
    $return['msg'] = 'You did not enter your message.';
    break;
}

break;
}

if (!$return['error'])
    $return['msg'] = "Thank you: {$_POST['name']}<br />email address: {$_POST['email']}<br />Your Message: {$_POST['message']}";


echo json_encode($return);
```

And here is the PHP script I use elsewhere for validation:

```
<?php

$subject = "Website Contact Form Enquiry";

//If the form is submitted

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

//Check to make sure that the name field is not empty
if(trim($_POST['contactname']) == '') {
    $hasError = true;
} else {
    $name = trim($_POST['contactname']);
}

//Check to make sure sure that a valid email address is submitted
if(trim($_POST['email']) == '')  {
    $hasError = true;
} else if (!eregi("^[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9._%-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$", trim($_POST['email']))) {
    $hasError = true;
} else {
    $email = trim($_POST['email']);
}

//Check to make sure comments were entered
if(trim($_POST['message']) == '') {
    $hasError = true;
} else {
    if(function_exists('stripslashes')) {
        $comments = stripslashes(trim($_POST['message']));
    } else {
        $comments = trim($_POST['message']);
    }
}

//If there is no error, send the email
if(!isset($hasError)) {
    $emailTo = 'info@bgv.co.za'; //Put your own email address here
    $body = "Name: $name \n\nEmail: $email \n\nComments:\n $comments";
    $headers = 'From: My Site <'.$emailTo.'>' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $email;

    mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers);
    $emailSent = true;

}
}
?>
```

Please can someone who know their PHP help me - I dont have a clue how to put this together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this. i think this code alone working good for what you want.

```
$subject = "Website Contact Form Enquiry";

//If the form is submitted

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

//Check to make sure that the name field is not empty
if(trim($_POST['contactname']) == '') {
    $hasError = true;
    $return['msg'] = 'You did not enter your name.';
} else {
    $name = trim($_POST['contactname']);
}

//Check to make sure sure that a valid email address is submitted
if(trim($_POST['email']) == '')  {
    $hasError = true;
    $return['msg'] = 'You did not enter your email.';
} else if (!eregi("^[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9._%-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$", trim($_POST['email']))) {
    $hasError = true;
    $return['msg'] = 'You did not enter valid email.';
} else {
    $email = trim($_POST['email']);
}

//Check to make sure comments were entered
if(trim($_POST['message']) == '') {
    $hasError = true;
   $return['msg'] = 'You did not enter your message.';
} else {
    if(function_exists('stripslashes')) {
        $comments = stripslashes(trim($_POST['message']));
    } else {
        $comments = trim($_POST['message']);
    }
}

//If there is no error, send the email
if(!isset($hasError)) {
    $emailTo = 'info@bgv.co.za'; //Put your own email address here
    $body = "Name: $name \n\nEmail: $email \n\nComments:\n $comments";
    $headers = 'From: My Site <'.$emailTo.'>' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $email;

    mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers);
    $emailSent = true;

}else{
  echo json_encode($return);

 }
}
```